# Derivation from a network

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, machine-learning, neural-networks

how can I represent the derivative of a network (e.g. NetGraph or NetChain) as a network? I have tried it with FunctionLayer[] and NetPortGradient, but without success.

I would be very pleased to receive an answer.

Minimal working example:

Let the following layer be given

```
unet = FunctionLayer[#*FeedForwardNet[#] + 1 &, "Output" -> "Scalar"]
```

whereby

```
FeedForwardNet = NetChain[ {LinearLayer[50, "Input" -> "Real"], LogisticSigmoid,LinearLayer[1, "Output" -> "Scalar"]}]
```

I now want to determine the derivative of unet, but as a network.

With

```
NetInitialize[unet][1, NetPortGradient["Input"]]
```

I get the derivative at the point 1. However, I cannot define this as a layer. When I try I get an error:

```
FunctionLayer[NetInitialize[u][#, NetPortGradient["Input"]] &]
```

Error: Cannot interpret FunctionLayer[<>][#1, #2] & as a network.

I would not like to carry out a numerical calculation of the derivative.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. In order to make the question more concrete, please add a minimal working example along with a desired output.

Comment: Hello, I have now done that. Thank you for the advice.